# Customise the mat table sorting from header icons

Tags: angular, mat-table, material-table, angular-material-table

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" [matSortDisableClear]="false">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columnHeader" [cdkColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
       <ng-container *ngIf="column.isSortable; else notSortable">
          <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ column.header }}
            <mat-icon class="arrowUp">arrow_upward</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon class="arrowDown">arrow_downward</mat-icon>
          </mat-header-cell>
       </ng-container>
       <ng-template #notSortable><mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{
          column.header
       }}</mat-header-cell></ng-template>
       <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ column.cell(row) }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

*CSS*

```
    .arrowUp,
    .arrowDown {
         height: 15px;
         width: 15px;
         font-size: 15px;
         opacity: 0.5;
       }
        .arrowUp {
          margin-left: 10px;
        }
        
        ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow[style] .mat-sort-header-stem {
          display: none;
        }
        ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow[style] .mat-sort-header-indicator {
          display: none;
        }
        ::ng-deep
          .mat-sort-header-arrow[style]
          .mat-sort-header-indicator
          .mat-sort-header-pointer-left,
        ::ng-deep
          .mat-sort-header-arrow[style]
          .mat-sort-header-indicator
          .mat-sort-header-pointer-right,
        ::ng-deep
          .mat-sort-header-arrow[style]
          .mat-sort-header-indicator
          .mat-sort-header-pointer-middle {
          display: none;
        }
        [aria-sort="ascending"] ::ng-deep .arrowUp {
          opacity: 1;
          pointer-events: none;
        }
        [aria-sort="descending"] ::ng-deep .arrowDown {
          opacity: 1;
          pointer-events: none;
        }
```

*Ts*

```
    import {
      AfterViewInit,
      Component,
      Input,
      OnInit,
      ViewChild,
    } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
    import { MatSort, Sort } from '@angular/material/sort';
    import { MatTable, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
    import { Column } from '../column.model';
    import { Exercise } from '../exercise.model';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-table',
      templateUrl: './table.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./table.component.css'],
    })
    export class TableComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      displayedColumns: string[] = [];
      dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Exercise>();
      activeSortColumn: any;
      activeSortDirection: any;
      constructor() {}
    
      @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
      @ViewChild(MatTable, { static: false }) table: MatTable<any>;
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator)
      paginator: MatPaginator;
    
      @Input('dataSource') tableData: Exercise[];
      @Input() isPageable = false;
      @Input() isFilterable = false;
      @Input() columnHeader: Column[];
      @Input() paginationSizes: number[] = [5, 10, 15];
      @Input() defaultPageSize = this.paginationSizes[1];
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataSource.data = this.tableData;
        this.displayedColumns = this.columnHeader.map((c: any) => c.columnDef);
      }
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }
      doFilter(filterValue: any) {
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.target.value.trim().toLowerCase();
      }
      sortData(event: any) {
        this.activeSortColumn = event.active;
        this.activeSortDirection = event.direction;
        console.log(this.activeSortColumn, this.activeSortDirection);
      }
    }
```

I want mat arrow icons instead of the default mat-sort trigger indicator which comes on header click to sort the column.
I can get the CSS correct which is getting the correct arrow whether it's ascending or descending but there is a loop of "asc" "desc" and "clear" for every column
I have no idea how to incorporate it with the mat-arrow icon so that whenever I click up arrow it sorts "asc" and vice versa; it should only happen on icon click and not the header div click.